# TypeScript+Jasmine when tested class is within module definition

Tags: unit-testing, typescript, jasmine, amd, chutzpah

I'm unable to figure out how to write a Jasmine test in TypeScript when the class to be tested is inside a module definition. This setup works fine:

Calculator.ts:

```
export class Calculator {
    add(x: number, y: number): number {
        return x + y;
    }
}
```

CalculatorTest.ts:

```
///<reference path="scripts/typings/jasmine/jasmine.d.ts"/>
///<reference path="../NancyApplication506/app/Calculator.ts"/>
import Calculator = require("../NancyApplication506/app/Calculator");

describe("Calculator tests", () => {
    var calculator: Calculator.Calculator;

    beforeEach(() => {
        calculator = new Calculator.Calculator();
    });
    it("should be able to add", () => {
        expect(calculator.add(21,21)).toBe(42);
    });
});
```

When I change Calculator.ts like this, however, I have been unable to figure out how to write my test.

```
module SomeModuleName {
    export class Calculator {
        add(x: number, y: number): number {
            return x + y;
        }
    }
}
```

I have tried dozens of different things, all resulting in complete failure. Please please please help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a Chutzpah.json file in the same directory as the tests:

```
{
    "Compile": {
        "Mode": "External",
        "Extensions": [ ".ts" ],
        "ExtensionsWithNoOutput": [ ".d.ts" ],
        "SourceDirectory": "../",
        "OutDirectory": "../"
    }
}
```

And just remove:

```
import Calculator = require("../NancyApplication506/app/Calculator");
```